# React Native -Error: Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'Home'. It must be a valid React Component

Tags: typescript, react-native, mobile, react-native-navigation

I have got this error message when I try to work this in Expo Go.

Error: Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'Home'. It must be a valid React Component.

This error is located at:
in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in RCTSafeAreaView (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

```
import React from 'react';
    import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
    
    
    const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <ImageBackground source={{ uri: 'https://www.kikajoy.com/kikajoy-luks-kutu-oyunu-tombala-yilbasi-kutu-oyunlari-kikajoy-8928-99-B.jpg' }} style={styles.imageBackground}>
            <View style={styles.topView}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>TOMBALA</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SinglePlayer')}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>SINGLE PLAYER</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MultiPlayer')}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>MULTIPLAYER</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </ImageBackground>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'linen',
        padding: 8,
      },
      imageBackground: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        resizeMode: 'contain',
      },
      topView: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 50,
      },
      title: {
        fontSize: 50,
        fontFamily: 'Comic Sans MS',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: '#ff0000',
      },
      button: {
        marginTop: 10,
        padding: 10,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#654321',
      },
      buttonText: {
        color: 'white', // Set the text color to make it visible
      },
    });
    
    export default HomeScreen

import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import TombalaSingle from './src/screens/TombalaSingle'
import TombalaMultiplayer from './src/screens/TombalaMultiplayer'
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

    export default function App() {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"Home"}>
        <Stack.Screen name={"Home"} component={HomeScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name={"SinglePlayer"} component={TombalaSingle}/>
        <Stack.Screen name={"MultiPlayer"} component={TombalaMultiplayer}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    }
    
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```